# generic interface implementation not recognized

Tags: go

Consider the following semi-contrived example of generated/legacy code that I'd prefer not to change. I am interested in writing a generic wrapper around this to emit metrics and logs as you'll see.

There is a wrapper around a single datatype for storage that can be encoded and decoded. There are 10 such datatypes in my codebase.

```golang
type LegacyData struct{}
```

A watcher to notify on changes to the data and retrieve that data

```golang
type LegacyWatch interface {
    Get() (*LegacyData, error)
}

type LegacyWatchETCD struct{}

func (l *LegacyWatchETCD) Get() (*LegacyData, error) {
    return &LegacyData{}, nil
}

func NewLegacyWatchETCD() LegacyWatch {
    return &LegacyWatchETCD{}
}
```

A storage engine to read, write, delete and get a watcher for changes to the data

```golang
type LegacyStorage interface {
    Watch(key string) (LegacyWatch, error)
}

type LegacyStorageETCD struct{}

func NewLegacyStorageETCD() LegacyStorage {
    return &LegacyStorageETCD{}
}

func (l *LegacyStorageETCD) Watch(key string) (LegacyWatch, error) {
    return NewLegacyWatchETCD(), nil
}
```

Finally, there is a provider method that a manager can use to operated on the data

```golang
func provideLegacyStorage() LegacyStorage {
    s := NewLegacyStorageETCD()
    return s
}
```

Now let's also suppose that the `LegacyData` struct is one of 10 datatypes that is being stored so that there are 10 storage and watcher objects for each data type. Much of this code is either generated from [genny](https://github.com/cheekybits/genny) or hasn't been touched for many years and I'd like to write a generic wrapper around this to emit metrics and logs for each of the storage operations.

To do this I first built a generic watch adapter

```golang
type Watch[T any] interface {
    Get() (*T, error)
}

type WatchAdapter[T any, W Watch[T]] struct {
    watch W
}

func NewWatchAdapter[T any, W Watch[T]](watch W) *WatchAdapter[T, W] {
    return &WatchAdapter[T, W]{
        watch: watch,
    }
}

func (s *WatchAdapter[T, W]) Get() (*T, error) {
    return s.watch.Get()
}
```

A generic storage adapter

```golang
type Storage[T any, W Watch[T]] interface {
    Watch(key string) (W, error)
}

type StorageAdapter[T any, W Watch[T]] struct {
    storage Storage[T, W]
}

func NewStorageAdapter[T any, W Watch[T]](storage Storage[T, W]) *StorageAdapter[T, W] {
    return &StorageAdapter[T, W]{
        storage: storage,
    }
}

func (s *StorageAdapter[T, W]) Watch(key string) (*WatchAdapter[T, W], error) {
    watcher, err := s.storage.Watch(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return NewWatchAdapter[T, W](watcher), err
}
```

And finally updated the provider method

```golang
func provideLegacyStorage() LegacyStorage {
    s := NewLegacyStorageETCD()
    // return s

    // year 2023 update
    a := NewStorageAdapter(s)
    return a
}
```

And I see the following error:

> ./prog.go:27:9: cannot use a (variable of type *StorageAdapter[LegacyData, LegacyWatch]) as LegacyStorage value in return statement: *StorageAdapter[LegacyData, LegacyWatch] does not implement LegacyStorage (wrong type for method Watch)
> have Watch(string) (*WatchAdapter[LegacyData, LegacyWatch], error)
> want Watch(string) (LegacyWatch, error)

Here is a [link](https://go.dev/play/p/sthkVubGLjI) to the go playground. I would have expected this to work because `LegacyWatch` technically is generically implemented by `*WatchAdapter[LegacyData, LegacyWatch]`.

I was able to fix this in two separate ways:

(1) By adding a wrapper struct specific to the `LegacyData` and `LegacyWatch`, however this is tedious as I mentioned earlier there are 10 different data types. Here is a [link](https://go.dev/play/p/refphsYDOCp) to the go playground for the first fix.

```golang
func provideLegacyStorage() LegacyStorage {
    s := NewLegacyStorageETCD()
    // return s

    // year 2023 update
    adapter := NewStorageAdapter(s)
    wrapper := NewWrapper(adapter)
    return wrapper
}

type Wrapper struct {
    adapter *StorageAdapter[LegacyData, LegacyWatch]
}

func NewWrapper(adapter *StorageAdapter[LegacyData, LegacyWatch]) *Wrapper {
    return &Wrapper{
        adapter: adapter,
    }
}

func (s *Wrapper) Watch(key string) (LegacyWatch, error) {
    return s.adapter.Watch(key)
}
```

(2) First by changing the "constructor" for `WatchAdapter` to return the generic interface `W` instead of its struct pointer `*WatchAdapter[T, W]`.

```golang
func NewWatchAdapter[T any, W Watch[T]](watch W) Watch[T] {
    return &WatchAdapter[T, W]{
        watch: watch,
    }
}
```

And then changing the return value for `StorageAdapter's` return value from the struct pointer `*WatchAdapter[T, W]` to the generic type `W` and casting the return to `W`.

```golang
func (s *StorageAdapter[T, W]) Watch(key string) (W, error) {
    watcher, err := s.storage.Watch(key)
    return NewWatchAdapter[T, W](watcher).(W), err
}
```

This just feels incredibly hacky to me. Here is a [link](https://go.dev/play/p/S4UhskADo6g) to the go playground.

It seems to me since both these "fixes" (1) and (2) work without issues and the language should be able to handle this. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Go types are invariant, you can’t have covariant return types https://go.dev/doc/faq#covariant_types

Comment: I see... in this case what is the recommended way to do this? From my listed fixes does (1) look more reasonable than (2), or vice versa? Or is there a 3rd way?

Comment: 1 is tedious as you say; 2 seems straightforward enough.